# Is there a common "class=>clazz" equivalent for "interface?

Tags: keywords

In most languages I've used it's common practice to replace the reserved word `class` with `clazz` when you have a variable that refers to a class.  This has become a sort of de facto convention, to the point where if I see `klass` it surprises me.

Is there any "replacement word" that's even close to as popular for the `interface` keyword?

Comment: what sort of terrible languages do you use where that is in any way a common practice?

Comment: @Telastyn Pretty much anything where `class` is a language keyword.

Comment: It's [especially common in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529974/why-do-java-programmers-like-to-name-a-variable-clazz). Is this proof that Java is a terrible language? ;)

Comment: I've worked with C#, C++, and Java for over 20 years now, and have _never_ seen this.

Comment: In my current case the language is Javascript, but I'm pretty sure I have seen the convention used in all the major languages that I've used (ie. Java, Python and Ruby).

Comment: This isn't technically an answer, but I really think it would be best to just use `class_` and `interface_`. Or, in C#, you can use `@class` and `@interface` instead.

Comment: @Telastyn Have you also done much work in domains in which `class` is a meaningful term for reasons unrelated to the typical OO use?

Comment: How about "interfaze"? Or "int3rfase"? Or "intrfz"? I can keep this on forever :-).

Comment: Heh, thanks @MartinMaat, but I was curious if there was any kind of standard, even a de facto one (I can makeup names too, but I'm looking for the name that results in the lowest number of "WTFs per minute" :) ).

Comment: Why you just don't call it "type"?

Comment: 15 years of programming, and I have never once have I been so overwhelmed by the desire to use the word "class" or "interface" as a variable that I resorted to a bastardized version of the word. Your brain has a built in thesaurus. Use that instead.

Comment: @ThalesPereira Perhaps because "type" isn't what they mean?

Comment: @riwalk Your and Telastyn's appeals to experience would be a lot more meaningful if you could provide evidence that you actually encounter situations where there is a strong temptation to use "class" or "interface." A farmer could spend decades growing crops in 70+ degrees F year-round Panama and never lose crops to frost. That doesn't mean Canada never experiences frost.

Comment: @machineghost  Seriously, I was not aware of the practice you mentioned either. It seems to me that whenever you need such a name it is in a context and you would want to use some meaningful prefix anyway, like CustomerClass or InvoiceInterface. Problem solved.

Comment: Um... `classInstance`, or simply `instance`? (if you really need such a thing.  Names this generic usually smell of some other problem in your design).

Comment: @MartinMaat I think your point (which others have made also) is valid: `FooInterface` is a great name.  However, there are cases where you don't know what the class is.  For instance, let's say you're augmenting a class inside a decorator.  The decorator takes an (unknown) class, modifies and returns it.  One could name that variable `classToBeDecorated`, but `clazz` is a bit more convenient, and is often used in such cases.

Comment: @8bittree, Seriously? Provide an example where there would be a strong temptation to use "class" or "interface" as a variable name, and I'll tell you what I would use instead. And your farmer example is absurd.

Comment: @riwalk No, you throwing around 15 context-free years of experience as if its the be-all, end-all is absurd. Want something more programming related? Tell me just what developing casual web games for 15 years tells one about writing a Raspberry Pi bootloader? Yes, there's some very general overlap, but the fact that the Pi's GPU starts up before the CPU isn't going to be a particularly frequent topic in web games. Now, if you spent a lot of that time working on, say, administration software for schools, a domain where "class" might come up frequently, your experience may be relevant.

Comment: @riwalk To be fair, you did also mention a thesaurus, which is a reasonable suggestion, but please don't claim context-free years of experience as proof that a context-sensitive thing can never happen.

Comment: Would you ever want to name your integer variable *int*? No, because it is meaningless - you call it length, age, years, count, ...  Although its tempting to call instances after their classes, it drops all semantical value. What object does this variable represent? Name it accordingly.

Comment: @8bittree A class and an interface are just types, as far as I understand. Sure, they have different _rules_, but in the end they are just types!

Comment: @ThalesPereira [Class](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class) and [interface](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interface) have meanings beyond those of OOP. Meanings that could very well be relevant if you're developing software in certain domains.

Comment: **Regarding your edit:** post that material on http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com, which is specifically designed for that purpose, not in your question here.  FWIW, questions that are merely answerable with yes or no are not all that interesting, and usually amount to [painting the bike shed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)

Comment: Not sure I would want a developer on my team that was lazy enough to use variables called, for example, `clazz`.  It's frankly ridiculous.

Comment: @DarrenYoung: It would only make sense in a metaprogramming context, i.e. if you're manipulating class representations.  It would never make sense in ordinary usage contexts.

Comment: I hate the sound of `clazz`. When I see it I replace it with `klass`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or if you're developing administrative software for schools, or software involved with [biological taxonomies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(biology)), or economic classes, or [licenses](https://www.reference.com/government-politics/class-d-license-7e4cd94ece5751ef), or [law](https://www.reference.com/government-politics/class-d-felony-1e4197b66d7d1105?qo=cdpArticles), or any of the myriad other uses for the word `class`.

Comment: @8bittree: Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Robert Harvey thanks for the edit; I was going to post on meta, but then I realized that whatever you did in your edit got this question out of the penalty box :)

Comment: @Telastyn So I take it you've never taken a look at [`java.lang.Class`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#2865) or written any code where you have to pass a class variable as a parameter? Admittedly, this isn't your average code, but anyone with at least a couple of years reading Java will have at least found this *once*. (By the way, yes, Java is a relatively clumsy language)

Comment: @DarrenYoung Then stop using Java, since Java itself is written using the `clazz` convention :)

Comment: @AndresF. Good job I don't use Java :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**.

If we're talking about Java, it's very rare that you need to distinguish a `Class` object as being distinct from an interface. They're all basically *types*, and calling them all classes is reinforced by the fact that there is only a `Class` class (with an `isInterface()` method), and they are compiled to `.class` files. So I've seen `clazz`, `cls`, `c` ... `clazz` is pretty common.

If you did need to reference something knowing full well that it was an interface, and you wanted to convey that fact, then you'd have to invent your own name; it's pretty unusual, and you only get conventions for frequently-used concepts.

If I felt *compelled* to select a name, then why not *intyMcInterface*? - seeing as how [Boaty McBoatface](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-36064659) topped the famous Name This Boat poll. Or you could call it *sirDavidAttenborough*, [like they ended up doing](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-36225652), but you might get some WTFs for that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you see people trying to name a variable for this is that you can indeed get an instance of the reflective `Class` object for a given object. I don't know of any equivalent object that represents the reflected metadata of an interface.

I would probably still just use `cls` anyway.

And I won't even troll you by "seriously" suggesting you name the variable `if` for InterFace.

Answer (score 0):

Using reserved words for variable names is bad form, but it can be done.

C# Example:

```
   string @interface = "Using reserved words for variable names is bad form.";
   Console.Write(@interface);
```

With this in mind.  If you have to use a reserved word, try and think of something similar to use instead.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interface

Or preface it with something specific:

- NetworkInterface
- DatabaseInterface

Comment: In C#, those would be `INetwork` and `IDatabase`

Comment: @Robert - Thx, updated answer to be more interface specific.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke; a variable of type `INetwork` would never have to be disambiguated, nor would you prefix the actual variable with `I`, only the type itself.